# PHPStorm не работает autoupload

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, ide, jetbrains

При нажатии `ctrl+s` не загружаются данные на сервер, приходится ручками нажимать кнопку upload.

В `Tools->Deployment->Automatic upload` стоит галочка. Варианты пробовал разные - и `always` и по факту нажатия `ctrl+s`

Mapping настроен - папка на сервере указана (не пустая строчка), локальная папка указана.

В настройках соединения root path тоже указана `upload external changes` тоже пробовал - с галочкой и без при нажатии `ctrl+s` внизу на доли секунды появляется текст `"automatic upload: wait for related changes to apply before upload"`. 
По факту на сервер файлы с изменениями при сохранении не загружаются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делал все по этому [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKH7kIRyURY). Предлагаю сбросить настройки по умолчанию. И выставить как у меня на скрине. Так все работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Помог сброс настроек. спасибо! сам же конфиг мой был аналогичен.